# Find which Chrome Tab is using Significant Energy

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Under the `Energy Monitor` in Yosemite, it shows Chrome having the highest energy impact. Is it possible to figure out which Chrome tab is the one that is consuming the most energy?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't appear so - Safari shows each 'helper' as a page URL, Chrome doesn't seem to

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Right click the table headers (App Name, Energy Impact, etc.) and check `Process ID`. Now you can see the PIDs associated with that `Energy Impact` values.

Next, click the 'customize/options' button in Chrome (it's the triple horizontal stripes button next to the URL bar) and go to `More Tools` > `Task Manager`, which brings up Chrome's internal task manager. In there you'll find the different Chrome threads (including running extensions and open tabs) with their names and PIDs.

You can then cross reference the PIDs between Chrome's task manager and Yosemite's Activity Monitor.

Comment: Chrome's task manager now includes sortable columns for CPU usage and memory footprint, which may alleviate the need to use MacOS's Activity Monitor.

Comment: Nice. But other than viewing the dynamically changing usage in the Chrome Task Manager, there is more at hand. No right click on the rows, but there are two useful actions:  (1) Single-click on a process in the list. Then as the list gets updated and resorted, you can follow the process of interest.  (2) Even better, double-click on the process in the list, and chrome brings that tab to the front!  Very handy, and it's usually the stupid tabs that look useful but have lots of ads, and lots of junk.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an answer to your specific question... but I think I have a pretty good solution for you for tabs eating up memory :) After putting in real work and time with 4 different browsers over the course of about 6 days, noting my device's performance under normal working conditions, and being flexible with workflows in each browser, I came back to Chrome.

I continued searching high and low for an answer to my dilemma with no luck because my 2017 Macbook Pro was... about to be tossed out my fifth story apartment. I ultimately came up with my own little solution, implementing two wonderful plugins. They also added some benefits that I didn't even know I needed, which is something that'll help you automatically saving your windows' state of tabs, while also along you to save collections of tabs manually.

I don't know how I've survived this long...

**"Chrome Tab Hoarder" and "Memory Efficiency" Achievements Unlocked!**
Confession - I knew my memory issues were caused by the fact that I had 15 browser tabs open. I can have triple that open now, no problem.

Get the [Toby Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toby-for-chrome/hddnkoipeenegfoeaoibdmnaalmgkpip?hl=en) to automatically save any and all browsing window states whether your computer stroked out or you quit Chrome on purpose. It's even better than what I was originally searching for because you can save (and edit at any point) Collections of tabs. This is by far my most used and favorite thing that I've discovered in 2020 (along with my web design software, Figma, and upgraded web development workflow).

The perfect companion extension for Toby is called [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg?hl=en). It will cause you to yell at the sky screaming profanities a lot less because your computer will run SO much better. Suspended tabs use significantly less energy and memory. If you have tabs open and don't use them within 30 minutes, it'll stay there in your tabs, but be suspended and not use resources. When you click on the tab, it reloads. It won't suspend any tabs that have input fields with information in them or ones that actively play videos or sounds. You have options to not suspend any tabs from a particular domain, particular URLs (I don't suspend Gmail, ClickUp, and some others), customize the amount of time before suspending a tab, etc

I hope this helps some people! It may sound like a lot but give it an honest couple of days and see what you think, especially those of us who are tab hoarders .

I literally have 46 tabs open right now between two different windows - oops  My 3-year-old MacBook Pro has that plus Photoshop and 6 other open apps. My embarrassing number of tabs (let's not talk about it) wasn't even a possibility before, neither was saving them.